# How to solve $1/2(1+a^n)-1/2(1-a^{-n})-1/(a^{-2n}-1)=1/2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation
$$\frac{1}{2(1+a^n)}-\frac{1}{2(1-a^{-n})}-\frac{1}{a^{-2n}-1}=\frac{1}{2}$$
There are a few conditions as well
$$a \neq 0$$
$$a \neq \pm 1$$
I don't know how to solve it and I tried using [Symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/), but I don't even understand the first step, which is
$$\frac{1}{2(1+a^n)}-\frac{a^n}{2(a^n-1)}-\frac{a^{2n}}{1-a^{2n}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Please, explain at least the first step.

Comment: Try multiplying by $1-a^{2n}$.

Comment: @Gibbs I guess... My workbook just says "Prove", though it doesn't say what.

Comment: J.G how you get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first step, for the second term you have
$$-\frac{1}{2(1-a^{-n})} = \frac{1}{2(a^{-n}-1)} = \frac{1}{2\left(\frac{1}{a^n}-1\right)} = \frac{1}{2\left(\frac{1-a^n}{a^n} \right)} = \frac{a^n}{2(1-a^n)} = -\frac{a^n}{2(a^n-1)}.$$
The third term can be expanded in the same way. Can you go on from here?

Answer (score 0):

For the first step, multiply the second fraction on top and bottom by $a^n$ and the third fraction on top and bottom by $a^{2n}$.  The the left side is

$$\frac{1}{2(1+a^n)} - \frac{a^n}{2(a^n-1)} - \frac{a^{2n}}{1-a^{2n}},$$

as you have.  Reverse the difference in the second fraction, which changes the minus to plus.  Also factor the denominator in the last fraction with "difference of squares" and you get

$$\frac{1}{2(1+a^n)} + \frac{a^n}{2(1-a^n)} - \frac{a^{2n}}{(1-a^{n})(1+a^n)}.$$

These three fractions have a common denominator of $2(1-a^{n})(1+a^n)$, so add the fractions:

$$\frac{1-a^n}{2(1-a^{n})(1+a^n)} + \frac{a^n(1+a^n)}{2(1-a^{n})(1+a^n)} - \frac{2a^{2n}}{2(1-a^{n})(1+a^n)} $$

$$=\frac{1-a^n + a^n(1+a^n) - 2a^{2n}}{2(1-a^{n})(1+a^n)}$$

$$= \frac{1-a^{2n}}{2(1-a^{2n})} = \frac{1}{2},$$

which was what you needed to prove.